Do we need to be translating the Hebrew form and meaning of the word hate in Romans 9:13?
The Romans 9:13 passage is derived from the Malachai 1:2-3 scripture where hated is hebrew not greek so should we look at scripture in the new testament that is from the old testament in a Hebrews translation light since Hate is not as strong of a meaning in Hebrew as it is in Greek does this mean "Hate" is not literal "Hate" as "Fear" is not "fear"?

The kind of hatred expressed in Malachi 1:2-3 is further explained in verse 4 The people against whom the LORD hath indignation for ever.


Romans 9:13 - As it is written, “Jacob I have loved, but Esau I have
hated.”


Short Answer: Yes, it’s at least beneficial to consider the Hebrew context for Old Testament references in the New Testament. Hermeneutically speaking, it’s important to consider both the original Hebrew intent and the possible shifts in meaning that could occur in the Greek translation.
The quotation of Malachi 1:2-3, uses the Greek word “ἐμίσησα” (emisēsa), translated as “I hated” in the INT. However, the original Hebrew word from Malachi is “שָׂנֵ֑אתִי” (śā·nê·ṯî), which has been argued to mean a literal hate to a more metaphorical sense of rejection or placing in a lower position of favor.
It's true “hate” can be less intense and more comparative, indicating a preference for one over another rather than an absolute detestation.
Looking at Barne's Notes on the Bible we see:

Have I hated - This does not mean any positive hatred; but that he had preferred Jacob, and had withheld from Esau those privileges and blessings which he had conferred on the posterity of Jacob. This
is explained in Malachi 1:3," And I hated Esau, and laid his mountains
and heritage waste for the dragons of the wilderness;" compare
Jeremiah 49:17-18; Ezekiel 35:6. It was common among the Hebrews to use the terms "love" and "hatred" in this comparative sense, where the former implied strong positive attachment, and the latter, not positive hatred, but merely a less love, or the withholding of the expressions of affection; compare Genesis 29:30-31; Proverbs 13:24,
"He that spareth his rod hateth his son; but he that loveth him
chasteneth him betimes;" Matthew 6:24, "No man can serve two masters,
for either he will hate the one and love the other," etc.; Luke 14:26,
"if any man come to me, and hate not his father and mother, etc."

Rather than a firm hatred, it may be that the verse is about God’s sovereign choice and the bestowing of His covenant blessings, where Jacob (Israel) was chosen to carry the promise, and Esau (Edom) was not. We see this played out in the blessings and heritage given to their descendants.
Matthew Poole says:

...There are some, that by Esau and Jacob do understand their posterity,
and not their persons; that say, the love and hatred of God, in the
forecited text, doth only or chiefly respect temporal things; God loved Jacob, i.e. he gave him the Land of Promise; but hated Esau, i.e. he gave him a dry and barren country, and made his mountain waste: that by God’s hating Esau, is only meant he loved him less than Jacob, &c. Such should consider, that the scope of the apostle is to
show, that some are the children of God, and of the promise, and not
others; and they must not make him cite testimonies out of the Old
Testament impertinently. Much is written pro and con upon this
argument. But I remember, he that writes a commentary must not too far involve himself in controversy.


Another example in the New Testament:

It helps to look at another example of the word "hate" in the New
Testament. Jesus said this to those who were deciding about whether to
follow Him or not: "If anyone comes to me and does not hate his own
father and mother and wife and children and brothers and sisters, yes,
and even his own life, he cannot be my disciple" (Luke 14:26).
Clearly, Jesus doesn't want us to carry bitter, angry feelings toward
our fathers, mothers, wives, and children. After all, we are commanded
in Scripture to honor our parents, love our wives, and to raise our
children wisely. In this case, the word "hate" is about comparison.
Jesus wanted disciples who were so deeply committed to Him that their
love for their family members looked like hate by comparison. (bibleref)





For further study:





Malachi 1:3 Commentaries: but I have hated Esau, and I have made his mountains a desolation and appointed his inheritance for the jackals of the wilderness.". (n.d.). https://biblehub.com/commentaries/malachi/1-3.htm



Romans 9:13 Commentaries: Just as it is written, “JACOB I LOVED, BUT ESAU I HATED.” (n.d.). https://biblehub.com/commentaries/romans/9-13.htm




While this question is almost a repeat of previous questions, the way it is asked is insightful, and it hasn't been asked in this way.  While the case is easier to show for the Hebrew word for love than for hate, the Hebrew words can portray the meaning favor versus disfavor or given attention verses ignored.
The Hebrew word for love in Malachi 1:2-3 is אהב.

אהב ...
qal: ...  —to like, to love (:: שׂנא): —1. a person: father his son ...
-- Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament (electronic ed., p. 18). E.J. Brill.

The Hebrew word for hate in Malachi 1:2-3 is שׂנא.

שׂנא ...
Arb. šaniʾa, šanaʾa to hate; the root is lacking in Akk., where zêru(m) (AHw. 1522; CAD Z: 97) is used for to dislike, hate, avoid.
qal: ...—2. sbj. אֵל/יהוה: —a. with acc. of the person אֹהֵב חָמָס Ps 11:5, נַחֲלָה Jr 12:8, עֵשָׂו Mal 1:3 --
Ibid., p. 1338-1339.


For more discussion see:
Do Malachi 1:2-3 & Romans 9:13 refer to God Loving Jacob & God Hating Esau as hyperbole or a...

Thank you and Loves Hamas was in the Hebrew is it violence or state? or both

The word Hamas has a different meaning in Hebrew (violence) from Arabic (zeal).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamas.  I don't see any connection to love.
